# Reference books on the Baum Connes conjecture

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory, topological-k-theory

Do there exist readable reference books about Baum-Connes Conjecture for beginners ?

Comment: To go along with written resources, here are two introductory lectures that might be worth looking into: Baum's "What is $K$-Theory and what is it good for?" at https://youtu.be/YXcSTY7l46s and Valette's "Some examples of the Baum-Connes assembly map" at https://youtu.be/GqlxQt45Y9s .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alain Valette, who is an active user on mathoverflow, has a book called *Introduction to the Baum-Connes connecture*. I remember reading parts of it a few years ago and finding it quite accessible and nicely written. However, I do not do research in this field, so I cannot say how up to date it is (if that is a concern for you).

Comment: Alain Valette (and others) recently posted a more up-to-date version of this book on the arxiv, see [this link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.10081).

Comment: @Awygan Thanks, I hadn't seen that yet. But is it really a version of this book? I only skimmed it briefly, but it seems to me that it might deserve a separate answer here.

Comment: I suppose that comment was a bit incorrect.  The 2019 paper is less of an introduction to the conjecture, and more of a survey of it.  Perhaps another answer is appropriate.