# Infinite (co)-homology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Lately, I've been wondering if it was possible to define singular homology also with infinite-dimensional simplices.
For example we could define an infinite dimensional simplex as:
$$\Delta_{\infty}:=\left\{\mathbf{x}\in [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}:\ \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}}x_i=1\right\}$$
(We could also impose $x_i=0$ almost everywhere).
$\Delta_{\infty}$ is a topological space equipped with the topology induced by the product topology of  $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Now given a topological space $X$, we could define:

$$ S_{\infty}(X):=\{\sigma:\Delta_{\infty}\to X : \ \sigma \ \text{is continous}\} $$

Normally the boundary operator is defined as:

$$\partial \sigma=\sigma\circ d_0 -\sigma\circ d_1+...(-)^n\sigma\circ d_n$$

Where $d_i$ embeds the $n-1$-simplex into the $n$-simplex by adding a $0$ in $i$-th coordinate.

If the simplex is infinite dimensional, adding a zero simply embeds $\Delta_{\infty}$ in itself.
So maybe(given a ring $R$) we could define a boundary operator $\partial_{\infty}$:

$$ 0 \to RS_{\infty}(X) \xrightarrow{\partial_{\infty}} RS_{\infty}(X) \xrightarrow{\partial_{\infty}} RS_{\infty}(X)  \to 0$$

Such that $\partial_{\infty}\circ \partial_{\infty}=0$. And we could define:

$$H_{\infty}(X):=\frac{\ker(\partial_{\infty})}{\text{im}(\partial_{\infty})}$$

The problem is that if the simplex is infinite dimensional, there are infinite $d_i$ so the alternating sum becomes infinite and meaningless(Moreover I don't know if this construction can be translated into a functor $\mathbf{Top}\to \mathbf{Mod}_R$, so that homeomorphic topological spaces have isomorphic infinite homologies).

Have you ever heard of a construction similar(even remotely) to this one? Is it a stupid idea?

(One could also approach this idea with cellular homology, by attaching also infinite dimensional disks to a CW-complex, but sincerely I didn't thought about this long enough).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may look what happens in case of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$.

Comment: @YoungMath What do you mean?

Comment: I am not expert enough to give some sound advice. But I'd suspect the above to be induced by a (co)limit construction in that case, or something like that.

Comment: Here are a very vague comment (inspired by symbolic dynamics/thermodynamic formalism): Instead of looking at $S_\infty$ it might be better to consider "locally constant"  $\sigma$'s (i.e. a continuous function $\sigma: \Delta_\infty\to X$ supported on some f.d. simplex) and incorporate the natural shift action on $\Delta_\infty$ into the coboundary operator (e.g. $d^1$ could be the difference between shift and identity).

Comment: If you believe that "infinite singular homology" should be the same as "infinite cellular homology" while also believing it should be homotopy invariant, then the answer is that it will always be trivial. This is because attaching an infinite dimension disk does not change the homotopy type since it is the cofiber of a map from the infinite dimensional sphere which is contractible.

Comment: @AlpUzman This is a very interesting idea. Basically in this way if $\sigma$ is non-zero only on the "$(n+1)$-subsimplex which has $i_0,...,i_n$ as entries. Then $\partial_{\infty}\sigma=\sigma\circ d_{i_0}-...(-)^{n}\sigma \circ d_{i_n}$. Right?

Comment: It seems like so, but like I said probably it would be better to somehow incorporate symmetries of indices (i.e. the shift operator) into the coboundary operator.

Comment: There is another relevant perspective from the point of view of operator $K$-theory, more specifically, the Baum-Connes conjecture; see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3767886/169085 and the lectures whose links I commented there, and the paper "Classifying Space for Proper Actions and $K$-Theory of Group $C^\ast$-algebras" by Baum, Connes and Higson, p. 248, the section titled "Discrete Groups".

Comment: Let us replace $\Delta_\infty$ by $\underline{E}\mathbb{Z}=\{f\in[0,1]^\mathbb{Z}\,|\, \#(\{f\neq0\})<\infty, \sum_n f(n)=1\}$. According to the paper I cited above, this is the universal model for proper $\mathbb{Z}$-actions. The Baum-Connes assembly map is a map from the $\mathbb{Z}$-equivariant $K$-homology of $\underline{E}\mathbb{Z}$ to some other kind of $K$-homology of $\mathbb{Z}$, and in this case the assembly map is an analog of the Poincare duality (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baum%E2%80%93Connes_conjecture#Examples ), and is an isomorphism.

Comment: The point of the Baum-Connes conjecture is to replace $\mathbb{Z}$ by more complicated groups and still have the assembly map to be an isomorphism. E.g. according to the Baum lecture I gave a link to in the M.SE link I gave above, it's unknown if one still has an isomorphism if $\mathbb{Z}$ is replaced by $\operatorname{SL}(3,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: I am not knowledgeable about these matters; I would speculate that now $X$ would be a proper $\mathbb{Z}$-space to serve as the coefficients of homologies (in which case it's probably better to have it as a well-behaved object), or some kind of extension.